# Base constructor not going back to child constructor

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone explains me why when calling child class cstr it goes to base constructor - clear part. But when in base cstr reaches MethodA() it will never go back to child constructor to set value Otherproperty. Why is that happen. For instance when i remove MethodA() from base it will go back to child ans set my variable. Don;t get it.

Base class cstr:

```
 Public Sub New(configpath As String, reportPath As String)
        _serializerPath = configpath
        _reportPath = reportPath
        MethodA() 
    End Sub
```

Child class cstr: (Inherits from base)

```
Public Sub New(configpath As String, reportPath As String)
        MyBase.New(configpath, reportpath)

        Otherproperty = "XXX"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `_MyBase`?  Shouldn't that be just `MyBase`?

Comment: @Chris Dunaway sorry just a typo

Comment: What does MethodA do? Also, are you seting the 'Otherproperty' properly? As in the example you posted you simple set it as a blank string.

Comment: @AugustoQ yes i set it.MethodA is method which is mutinherit for all childs so also by my child class so it's calling child class implementation of it.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the 'Otherproperty'? After the object has been built or during the execution of MethodA? Also, are you sure there isn't any exception occuring in MethodA?

Comment: @AugustoQ no error occuring anywhere. I think that doesn;t matter when MethodA finalize its execution it should go back to child constructor and set Otherproprty isnt it?

Comment: Yes. it should. I made a few tests here and everything went as expected, The property was set correctly even after the call of a Mustoverride method inside the base constructor.

Comment: @AugustoQ Can you provide your example?